# Been is confusing me HELP!

Tags: grammar, tense, past-tense, modal-verbs, past-perfect

I was watching tv series where police said “he could have been wearing gloves’ I think he speculated the past event..but I really can't understand the reason behind using ing and been...because we usually speculate past thing something like that “they could have gone there” I want to know the meaning and you can give me more example like this

Comment: Do you mean as opposed to *...could have **worn** gloves*? Often it's just a stylistic choice.

Comment: It doesn't need a transitive verb. "I could have been working" is a very common construction. I am working, I was working, I have been working.

Comment: Quote marks in English are “ and ” .  Don't use ((( ))) to delimit quotes.  The ((( ))) has been used by various anti-semitic groups, that you probably don't want to be associated with. Please remember to spell correctly:  The correct spelling of I is never i.

Answer (score 3):

*Have* + past participle => perfect (eg *I have seen*)

*Be* + present participle => continuous (eg *I am wearing*)

Put them together and you get

*Have* + past participle of *be* + present participle => perfect continuous (eg *I have been wearing*)

*I have worn gloves* usually means "On at least one occasion, not necessarily recently, I wore gloves" - the "present relevance" indicated by the perfect here means "These occasions occurred over a period extending up to the present (even if there didn't happen to be a recent occasion)".

*I have been wearing gloves* focuses on the wearing as a continuing event: it usually indicates a recent occasion.